# Optimization of SwaggerResponse

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

This is the top of my endpoint in an ASP.NET Core controller:

```
    [SwaggerResponse(200, "Successful", typeof(OperationResult<List<GetAllEventDTO>>)]]
    [SwaggerResponse(400, "InvalidationError", typeof(OperationResult<ValidationError>))]]
    [SwaggerResponse(401, "Not Authorised", typeof(OperationResult<Error>))]]
    [SwaggerResponse(403, "No access to execute action", typeof(OperationResult<Error>))]]
    [SwaggerResponse(404, "Not found", typeof(OperationResult<Error>))]]
    [SwaggerResponse(405, "Method not allowed", typeof(OperationResult<Error>))]]
    [SwaggerResponse(415, "Medias type not allowed", typeof(OperationResult<Error>))]]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AllEvent()
```

I wanted to create examples of errors and responses that a user might get as a result of a call but the design is too massive and I'm looking for ways to reduce it or move it elsewhere. Are there any options?

I recently found out about the existence of partial methods but they can only be of type void so it's probably not suitable for me?

Comment: Make an aggregated attribute where its constructor accept `Type` to return for 200, and internally handles the general ones? Haven't looked into `SwaggerResponseAttribute`, not sure if that's possible though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure response examples in code is the best place for something like this.  I've had success using postman to call the endpoint with payloads that will trigger the various success/failure responses, and from there you can save them off as examples to automatically generated documentation.